# how to run springboot init.d service as non root user?

Tags: spring-boot, unix, init.d

This is my springboot service which I created under/etc/init.d.

I sudo as springboot user and run service like

**springboot@xxx~$ sudo service springboot-smsmgmt.service start** which starts service as root user.

How can I run it as non-root (springboot user)?

Please note that I have to run command as sudo ( sudo service springboot-smsmgmt.service start)

```
#!/bin/sh
SERVICE_NAME=SMS-Gateway
PATH_TO_DEPLOY_DIR=/opt/springboot/smsmgmt
JAR_NAME=smsmgmt.jar
PID_PATH_NAME=/tmp/SMS-Gateway.pid
PROFILE_NAME=ASM
JAVA_PATH=/etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.8.0/bin/java
JAVA_CONF="-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"

case $1 in
    start)
        echo "Starting $SERVICE_NAME ..."
        PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
        if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ] && [ ! -z "$PID" ] &&  kill -s 0 $PID; then
           echo "$SERVICE_NAME is already running ..."
        else
           nohup $JAVA_PATH $JAVA_CONF -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=$PROFILE_NAME $PATH_TO_DEPLOY_DIR/$JAR_NAME  > /opt/springboot/smsmgmt/logs/smsapp.log  & echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME
           echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."

        fi
    ;;
    stop)
        if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stoping ..."
            kill $PID;
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ..."
            #rm $PID_PATH_NAME
            cat /dev/null > $PID_PATH_NAME
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
        fi
    ;;
    restart)
        if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopping ...";
            kill $PID;
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ...";
            #rm $PID_PATH_NAME
            cat /dev/null > $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME starting ..."
            nohup $JAVA_PATH $JAVA_CONF-jar -Dspring.profiles.active=$PROFILE_NAME $PATH_TO_DEPLOY_DIR/$JAR_NAME > /opt/springboot/smsmgmt/logs/smsapp.log & echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
        fi
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: 1) init.d services are typically run as "root" 2) [sudo](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) allows you to run a command as *any* user (any user you have privileges to run as).     Soooooo - if you want to run a script or a program as a specified user - then simply "sudo" that script or program :)  Problem solved :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for comment. I am new to Unix and not sure how can I do that. Any example would be helpful

Comment: It sounds like your *actual* question is "How do I auto-start my Spring Boot application at system boot"?  The answer is "it depends". In particular, it depends which version of *nix.  If this is a "production server", I would *definitely* seek guidance from your system administrator.  But look here, at 57.1.1 and 57.1.2 for the customary options, "System V" and "systemd": https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.RC1/reference/html/deployment-install.html

Comment: I figured it  out

Answer (score 1):

here is how I did it

**su - springboot -c** "nohup $JAVA_PATH $JAVA_CONF  -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=$PROFILE_NAME $PATH_TO_DEPLOY_DIR/$JAR_NAME  > /opt/springboot/smsmgmt/logs/smsapp.log  & echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME"

```
 #!/bin/sh
SERVICE_NAME=SMS-Gateway
PATH_TO_DEPLOY_DIR=/opt/springboot/smsmgmt
JAR_NAME=smsmgmt.jar
PID_PATH_NAME=/tmp/SMS-Gateway.pid
PROFILE_NAME=ASM
JAVA_PATH=/etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.8.0/bin/java
JAVA_CONF="-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"

case $1 in
    start)
        echo "Starting $SERVICE_NAME ..."
        PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
        if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ] && [ ! -z "$PID" ] &&  kill -s 0 $PID; then
           echo "$SERVICE_NAME is already running ..."
        else
           su - springboot -c "nohup $JAVA_PATH $JAVA_CONF  -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=$PROFILE_NAME $PATH_TO_DEPLOY_DIR/$JAR_NAME  > /opt/springboot/smsmgmt/logs/smsapp.log  & echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME"
           echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."

        fi
    ;;
    stop)
        if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stoping ..."
            su - springboot -c "kill $PID";
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ..."
            #rm $PID_PATH_NAME
            cat /dev/null > $PID_PATH_NAME
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
        fi
    ;;
    restart)
        if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopping ...";
            su - springboot -c "kill $PID";
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ...";
            #rm $PID_PATH_NAME
            cat /dev/null > $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME starting ..."
            su - springboot -c "nohup $JAVA_PATH $JAVA_CONF  -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=$PROFILE_NAME $PATH_TO_DEPLOY_DIR/$JAR_NAME  > /opt/springboot/smsmgmt/logs/smsapp.log  & echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME"
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
        fi
    ;;
esac
```